# How to use df.withColumn() when second argument is string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a dataframe `df` and do the following:

```
df = df.withColumn('age2', df.age + 2)
```

We get a new dataframe. Suppose that `df.age + 2` is being read in from a file (so it is a string). How do you convert this into a column expression without using `eval`?

Comment: "without using `eval`" - you mean, you don't want to use it, or you don't know how to use it? The following works: `df = df.withColumn('age2', eval('df.age + 2'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text is a valid Spark SQL expression, e.g., `age + 2`, then you can simply use `expr` from `pyspark.sql.functions` to transform it into a column:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('age2', F.expr('age + 2'))
```

If the text is rather Python source code as in `df.age + 2`, then you don't have many alternatives that do not involve `eval` or a reimplementation of it.

If the text is neither a valid Spark SQL expression nor valid Python code, you need to write a parser for whatever grammar that text has and write code to transform expressions in that grammar to calls into the Spark API.